# Can't use NVIDIA GeForce, only integrated Intel graphics

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card

I just bought a new Asus N53J XE-1 laptop that comes with a NVIDIA GeForce 425M. But when I check my graphics card with `dxdiag`, I can see only the Intel HD graphic.

When I try to set a game with a graphic card I also get only one option, the Intel HD.

All the drivers for NVIDIA are installed , but I can't use it for some reason. Any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 2):

Many recent laptop models now come with "switchable graphics"...two graphics cards designed to switch between them depending on the circumstances. Unfortunately, the mechanism for managing these graphics is far from standardized, and each laptop manufacturer has their own solution for management. Looking on Asus' support website, I don't know exactly which utility is used to manage the cards, but I'm guessing it's probably Power4Gear, which is their power management utility.

Alternatively, there may be a BIOS option to force nvidia graphics all the time, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: thank you for the answer . let mew get it right , the nvidia suppose to work automaticly when needed ?