# Integrated graphics card being used over NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M in Toshiba laptop?

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card, toshiba-laptop, nvidia-graphics-card

On my Toshiba laptop with a discrete GeForce GT 540M graphics card, as well an integrated Intel HD 3000, it seems like the discrete graphics card is never used. Games run like the Intel HD 3000 is being used, and various settings on the computer have an unchangeable setting of having the Intel HD card selected instead.

Some examples:

Under Device Manager, Display Adapters has listed two things, Intel HD and NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M.

But under dxdiag, display, only the Intel HD is listed.

The issue is along the same lines of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/222823/cant-use-nvidia-geforce-only-integrated-intel-graphics) and [this Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/1dnaoc/toshiba_website_says_i_have_nvidia_geforce_gt540m/)

Im guessing im having an "Optimus" issue as well?

Im wondering if anyone has found a way to fix this, since those two links are old. Ive downloaded latest NVIDIA drivers as per the Geforce Experience program, 340.52. And am on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: There are two ways to use the discrete card.  One disable the intel card in BIOS the other is don't install a driver for the intel card and use a Nvidia driver that doesn't support switching between the cards (I.e don't use OEM drivers )

Comment: @Ramhound , I updated to latest BIOS from Toshiba laptop, and there is no mention of anything graphics related :(. This second method sounds good to explore as i just reimaged this computer, nothing on it, but im not sure i understand fully. Do you mean i should get nvidia drivers from Toshiba or Nvidia?

Comment: Nvidia isn't a Windows OEM

Comment: I got the ones i have now from nvidia utility, not toshiba, but i didn't uninstall the original OEM ones first, nor have i disabled intel drivers. Is there a specific order in which i should go about this? Its fine if somethign gets messed up as there is recovery partition to do reinstall from.

Comment: It sounds like using both may be the only option... http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72567/can-i-force-steam-to-use-my-nvidia-gpu-instead-of-the-integrated-intel-card

Comment: Please indicate the OS, distribution, and version.  Second, please indicate the specific Nvidia card.